# Firefox & Safari - always show horizontal scrollbars if needed

Tags: safari, firefox, macos

Today I opened this fancy photo website of a friend. [It has horizontal scrolling of pictures.](http://themespectrum.com/scroll-demo/) In Firefox I cannot scroll horizontally without first using the cursor keys. The same happens in Safari. The horizontal scrollbar shows for a second, and if I hover over it, a bigger scrollbar appears and that one stays even longer, like 10 seconds. Then it disappears and I have to use the cursor again.

In my opinion this is a GUI failure by either Apple or Mozilla, but besides complaining I want to have this fixed. I want to see a horizontal scrollbar whenever I hover over the bottom border of the page in Firefox, if (and only if) the page is wider than the browser window. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Could you post a link to the site? Does the behavior differ in Chrome or Safari? It could be a problem from the site programmer.

Comment: I added a link in the question. It's a common problem with a theme similar to this one: http://themespectrum.com/scroll-demo/